# I want to show two series on a chart in c#

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I want to show two series, one for S based on sum(Pc) and the other for R based on Sum(Pc), how could I change my code to show both series without Error.

This is my code:

```
form_load()
{
  chart1.Series.clear();
  string cs=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionSrings["dbcs"].connectionString;
  using(SqlConnection Con=new SqlConnection(cs))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select distinct(S),distinct(R),sum(PC) from mytable group by S,R",con);
    Series series=chart1.Series["Series"];
    Con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
      series.Points.AddXY(rdr["S"].tostring(),rdr["PC"]);
      series.Points.AddXY(rdr["R"].tostring(),rdr["PC"]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Instead of `select distinct(S), ...` write `select distinct S, ...` and the code becomes much clearer.

Comment: @jarlh sorry, I do not get your comment.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function!!! Simply remove the parentheses around S. They are not needed and make no difference!

Comment: What error do you get? please be specific. Also did you even add a second series???

Answer (score 0):

You can another series, like so;

```
Series newSeries = new Series("test");
Chart1.Series.Add(newSeries);
```

You can then populate it's values using the same method you use for your original series, `newSeries.Points.AddXY(etc)`